# PRIMARY and FOREIGN key in one field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: `users`, `pages` and `users_pages`

```
Users Table
+----+------+-----
| id | name | ...
+----+------+-----

Pages Table
+----+------+-----
| id | name | ...
+----+------+-----

users_pages table, which says, which user is admin of which page.
+---------+---------+
| user_id | page_id |
+---------+---------+
|    1    |    1    |  // means, user 1 is admin of page 1
+---------+---------+
```

in `users_pages` table, combination of `user_id` and `page_id` is a compound key ( primary key )
Is it possible to define `user_id` and `page_id` as foreign key while they both together are primary key?

Comment: Yes. This is a fairly common (and good) design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Absolutely. You havn't mentioned which relational database you are using, but this is common practice, and allowable in all relational databases i know of.

*My attempt at an additional explanation:-*

Primary and foreign keys are more like 'theoretical' things rather than hard physical things. When looking at the nuts and bolts, I find it useful to think of only **indexes** and **contraints**, not of 'keys' as such

Thinking this way a 'primary key' is actually a combination of two separate things :-

1. A **unique contraint**. This checks for and refuses any attempts to
   create duplicates.
2. An **index** based on the field. This just makes
   it much faster to retrieve the record if you use that field to look
   it up (select * from table where pkey = 'x')

A 'foreign key' in practice is just a contraint, not much different from the unique key contraint. It checks the records exist in the other table, and refuses any attempts to create records with no corresponding entries in the referred to table.

There is no reason why you cant have multiple contraints on the same field (that it is both unique and exists in another table), and whatever indexes is on the table in no way prevents you from adding any contraint you like. Therefore there is no problem having the same field as part of a primary key and it also have a foreign key contraint.